# DataRow Delete without firing CurrentChanged Event

Tags: c#, event-handling, datarow

Well, I have the following problem:

I need to delete a row from a bindingsource without fireing the CurrentChanged event. Deletion is working without any problems. But it raises the CurrentChanged event instantly, which leads to my code matching to the CurrentChanged event is being executed. That leads to a problem.
Is there any way to achieve a similar effect like `.Delete()` without raising the event?

Comment: its a DataGridView connected to a bindingsource (SQLite Db) to be precise

Comment: I don't know do you realy realy need to do it or some other way exsists to do what you need. but you can add bool flag, set it to true when delete record and check it in event handler and set it to false

Comment: It is a good practice to notify ui when some record removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting a row will always raise the event, if there are any subscribers.

If the event code is under your control, you could set a flag which you check in the BindingSource_CurrentChanged event handler:

```
private void DeleteRow()
{
  this.justDeletedRow = true;
  this.bindingSource.DeleteRow(...);
}

protected void BindingSource_CurrentChanged(object sender ...)
{
  if (this.justDeletedRow)
  { 
     this.justDeletedRow = false;
     return;
  }

  // Process changes otherwise..
}
```

If the code isn't under your control - if you're binding to a component, say - then you can unbind the handler while performing the operation:

```
private void DeleteRow()
{
  this.bindingSource.CurrentChanged -= this.component.BindingSource_CurrentChanged;
  this.bindingSource.DeleteRow(...);
  this.bindingSource.CurrentChanged += this.component.BindingSource_CurrentChanged;
}
```

Comment: I did it by unsubscribing shortly. But i think the flag is a better idea... thanks!